# Small response in digital logic simulation

Tags: digital-logic, simulation, logic-gates

[image]

I am a student and new to digital logic simulations. Just curious as to why there is a very short response in OUT_02 at about 1.75 s.

Comment: Why? Because the logic circuit will produce that pulse. Can you justify why it shouldn't be there? I can't justify why it shouldn't be there --> is it intentionally there i.e. is it a wanted feature? Can you say why you believe it to be unwanted?

Comment: Perhaps to see it better, you should increase counter frequency.

Comment: As you're a strudent, Andy's comment is really very much better than my "logic" answer.  Something about that short pulse it made you think it was strange and perhaps undesirable.  What made you think that?

Answer (score 1):

You noticed something important and you should follow it up to find out what exactly is causing it.

It looks like there is a race condition in the logic, such as the term `in_03 xor out_01` appearing somewhere, and at t = 1.75 s one of them changes fractionally before the other.  Short, but not so short that your simulation misses it.

In fact, it is very possible there are [glitches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch#Electronics_glitch) at t = 0.25 s and t = 2.25 s, but the resolution of your simulation doesn't show them.